# Lexical Decision (Web-)App

Tags: methodology, experimental-psychology, software, linguistics

I want to make a lexical decision experiment, is there any freely available software for this? A Javascript-based webapp would suit me best, as it would run in the browser without the need to install anything.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Inquisit Web Edition](http://www.millisecond.com/).
 Here is an example script with a [lexical decision task](http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/LexicalDecisionTask/).

Unfortunately, it is **not free** and it requires installation of a **plug-in**.

Version 4 of Inquisit runs on OSX and Windows. Thus, it wont work in Linux or on phones, tablets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, I ended up writing simple [web-based lexical decision task software](https://github.com/MixayKocek/WebLexDec) myself.